# Slow down video using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to slow down a video using jquery. I found some documentation about how to do this with vanilla javascript, but how do I do this with jquery?

```
var video = document.getElementsByClassName("slow-video");
video.playbackRate = 20.5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `prop()` method to do this through jQuery.

However, note that a `playbackRate` of `20.5` will be ignored as it's outside the bounds of most browsers. `0.25` - `4.0` is the most commonly accepted value range.

```js
$('.slow-video').prop({
  volume: 0.15,
  playbackRate: 0.5 // half speed
});
```

```css
video { width: 450px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video class="slow-video" autobuffer controls autoplay>
  <source id="mp4" src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```